# Not getting any Facebook album data from Graph API response

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

My call to 'FB.api()' doesn't return anything for albums. Am I missing something here? The pics below show Graph API explorer erroring with no access token, so I'm assuming one is required?

I can use just '/me' as a param and I get back public data, so I know it's calling the server!

```js
FB.api('/me/albums', 'get', { access_token : userToken}, function (response) {
var r = response;
for (var i = 0, l = response.data.length; i < l; i++) {
    var z = 0;
}
});
```

With access token

[image]

With NO access token

[image]

Comment: you should take a look at the docs about how FB.api works with parameters. and yes, of course you need an access token. how else would facebook know who "/me" is? i mean, the error message tells you exactly that.

Comment: well, because there are lots of other posts on SO that say you don't need an access token if your logged in!

Comment: i guess you misunderstood. one point of using one of the SDKs is that you don´t have to deal with the access token, but it is always needed. for example, if you use FB.login and FB.getLoginStatus, you can just use FB.api without any token. that does not mean the api call does not need a token. think about it, how would facebook detect who "/me" is without a user token?

Comment: I thought maybe the token was stored under the hood. Like in a cookie or variable